# Getting a list of jtokens that contain a certain property value

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

I have this json:

```
{
"IsSuccess": true,
"Message": "Success",
"ResponseData": [
    {
        "ContentID": null,
        "ProductVersionEvritChildren": "0.22",
        "BookVisualsVersion": "0.17",
        "iconDescriptionPage": "Images/Products/covers_2018/lionTutIconPng.png",
        "IsBetaOnly": false,
        "ProductType": 8,
        "ProductID": 8337

    },
    {
        "ContentID": null,
        "ProductVersionEvritChildren": "0.12",
        "BookVisualsVersion": "0.12",
        "iconDescriptionPage": "Images/Products/covers_2018/BialikPngIcon.png",
        "IsBetaOnly": false,
        "ProductType": 8,
        "ProductID": 8352

    },
    {
        "ContentID": null,
        "ProductVersionEvritChildren": "0.13",
        "BookVisualsVersion": "0.12",
        "iconDescriptionPage": "Images/Products/covers_2018/ariotPngIcon.png",
        "IsBetaOnly": false,
        "ProductType": 8,
        "ProductID": 8342

    },
    {
        "ContentID": null,
        "ProductVersionEvritChildren": "0.14",
        "BookVisualsVersion": "0.12",
        "iconDescriptionPage": "Images/Products/covers_2018/magicHatPngIcon.png",
        "IsBetaOnly": false,
        "ProductType": 8,
        "ProductID": 8343

    },
    {
        "ContentID": null,
        "ProductVersionEvritChildren": "0.11",
        "BookVisualsVersion": "0.12",
        "iconDescriptionPage": "Images/Products/covers_2018/littleMichalPngIcon.png",
        "IsBetaOnly": false,
        "ProductType": 8,
        "ProductID": 8347
    }
]
```

}

and I have this given list of ProductID:

```
  private static readonly List<string> FreeBooksProductId = new List<string>()
    {
        "8352",
        "8347"
    };
```

and I want to get a list of jtonkens that contain a ProductID that I have in the list.

I know that there is a SelectTokens method that can give what I'm looking for but I don't know how do I use it when I need to check it with the list.

Comment: use a where with contains in linq . need to deserialize  your JSON

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you deserialize the posted JSON to below class schema and use a LINQ query to get the desired data. like

```
public class ResponseData
{
    public object ContentID { get; set; }
    public string ProductVersionEvritChildren { get; set; }
    public string BookVisualsVersion { get; set; }
    public string iconDescriptionPage { get; set; }
    public bool IsBetaOnly { get; set; }
    public int ProductType { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public List<ResponseData> ResponseData { get; set; }
}

var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);

data.ResponseData.Where(r => FreeBooksProductId.Contains(r.ProductID)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it's better to deserialize the `JSON` into an object, You can however still use the [`SelectTokens`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm) method that you have mentioned.

Assuming `json` is a `string` variable containing your posted `JSON`, you can use this snippet:

```
JObject parsedJson =  JObject.Parse(json);
List<JToken> listOfDesiredTokens = parsedJson.SelectTokens("ResponseData").Children()
                                             .Where(x => FreeBooksProductId.Contains((string)x.SelectToken("ProductID")))
                                             .ToList();
```

You'll get a list of `JToken` where the product id is contained in `FreeBooksProductId` list.

Comment: This answer for me too. but I'm deserializing the JSON anyway, and it easier to manipulate its data while its deserialize.